# Remove and insert characters into query result

Tags: sql

I want to know how to best modify a query result for use in a callflow query.
The numbers are all in national format but the PBX recieves international format.

So cut +32 and insert 0.

Comment: Hi, welcome, please read through this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557 and edit your question with relevant information.

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(number_column, '+32', '0'); `

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. The base query : select [Phonenumer] from [Client_view] where [Phonenumber] = '@PhoneNumber'       The variable is provided by the Contact center itself.

Comment: Following statement is executed succesfully but fails to show a result. select REPLACE(Number_variable, '+32', '0') from Number_column where Number_variable = '+3250289810'. The number variable is modified by the PBX itself.

Comment: @Justinas, Implementing the replace after the WHERE statement solved my issues. Thanks for the help and apologies for my dumb question.